# How to go to base url too after passing params on route?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

`<Route path="/skiday/:submenu" component={App}/>`
How can i go to skiday page before and after passing params?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?(!)

```js
<Route path="/skiday/:submenu" component={App}/>
<Route path="/skiday" component={App}/>
```

if this is the case you have to define another route to navigate. you can choose anothe component for no param mode if you want

Comment: That is what ive done and it wont work. It results 'skiday/add-day' when I want is '/add-day' when i click on 'addday' menu